# Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int - function cast not work

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, sql-server-2008-r2

Good day.

I know that this question very popular, but i don't see help for me...

**Structure database:**

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ExPRoG_Statistic_banners](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [user_id] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [banner_idn] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [banner_page] [varchar](150) NULL,
    [action] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [datetime] [datetime] NULL,
    [server_referer] [varchar](150) NULL,
    [ip] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [browser] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [id_firm] [varchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
```

**SQL:**

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 
          id
        , [user_id]
        , [day] = DAY(datetime)
    FROM Table
    WHERE banner_idn='50927853' AND datetime BETWEEN '2013-08-08 00:00:000' AND '2013-08-22 00:00:000'
) src
PIVOT 
(
    SUM(cast(id as bigint)) FOR [day] IN (
        [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10],
        [11], [12], [13], [14], [15], [16], [17], [18], [19], [20],
        [21], [22], [23], [24], [25], [26], [27], [28], [29], [30], [31])
) pvt
```

i make select, but i have error:

```
Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.
```

Type input id - int.

For remove error i want use cast() - `cast(id as bigint)`, but now i get error `Incorrect syntax near '('. for line cast(id as bigint)`

Tell me please where error?

Tell me please how remove error?

Comment: What is the datatype on the `id` column?  I might also suggest moving the `cast(id as bigint)` to the subquery instead of the `sum()` for clarity.

Comment: Why are you summing `id` columns anyway?

Comment: @bluefeet `id` datetipe `int`

Comment: @AlexN Can you edit your post and add some sample data from yourtable?

Comment: @bluefeet i add structure table in question, see please.

Comment: @AlexN Why are you summing the id column?  If that is an identity column, then how is sum going to mean anything?  Do you want to count the number of ids for each day?

Comment: One reason for summing is that PIVOT requires an aggregate function. If there's only one row per day, then it's fine to use SUM. MAX, MIN would be fine, too.

Comment: I don't have a compiler with me at the moment, but is it possible that PIVOT columns cannot be expressions? That they must be columns from the source? Like bluefeet suggested, move the cast into src.

Comment: @JohnTseng - If there was only one row being summed it would be impossible for an overflow to occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one -

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 
          id
        , [user_id]
        , [day] = DAY([datetime])
    FROM dbo.[Table]
    WHERE banner_idn = '50927853' 
        AND [datetime] BETWEEN '20130808' AND '20130822'
) src
PIVOT 
(
    COUNT(id) FOR [day] IN (
        [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10],
        [11], [12], [13], [14], [15], [16], [17], [18], [19], [20],
        [21], [22], [23], [24], [25], [26], [27], [28], [29], [30], [31])
) pvt
```

Comment: `SUM(cast(id as bigint))`

Comment: i know, but why i cannt usethis operation?